# wget command to download web-page & rename file with with html title?

Tags: html, awk, wget

I would like to download an html web-page and have the filename be the title of the html page.

I have found a command to get the html title:

```
wget -qO- 'https://www.linuxinsider.com/story/Austrumi-Linux-Has-Great-Potential-if-You-Speak-Its-Language-86285.html/' |   gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v RS='</title' 'RT{gsub(/.*<title[^>]*>/,"");print;exit}'
```

And it prints this: Austrumi Linux Has Great Potential if You Speak Its Language | Reviews | LinuxInsider

Found on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103252/how-do-i-get-a-websites-title-using-command-line

How could i pipe the title back into wget to use it as the filename when downloading that web-page?

EDIT: in case there is no way to do this directly in wget, i found a way to simply rename the html files once downloaded

[Renaming HTML files using <title> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389631/renaming-html-files-using-title-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't wget a file, analyze it's contents and then make the same wget execution that downloaded the file magically go back in time and output it to a new file named after it's contents that you analyzed in step 2. Just do this:

```
wget  '...' > tmp &&
name=$(gawk '...' tmp) &&
mv tmp "$name"
```

Add protection against `/` in `name` as necessary.

Comment: thank you, also seemed best to go that way (was just checking)