# Renaming HTML files using <title> tags and publication date

Tags: python, html, awk, beautifulsoup, rename

I would like to rename HTML files using the HTML title tags & the publication date.

I found an answer for the title using the title tags here:

Edited Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find . -type f | grep \.html)
   do
   title=$( awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<title>|</title>";RS=EOF} {print $2}' "$f" )
   mv -i "$f" "${title//[ ]/-}".html
done
```

[Renaming HTML files using <title> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389631/renaming-html-files-using-title-tags)

not sure how to get the date part working.

The result would be title_PublicationDate.html

Here is an example url: https://www.voltairenet.org/article178442.html

That would be renamed from "article178442.html" to "You Are The Hope by Paul Craig Roberts_20130508.html"

Here are the lines that have the publication date in them:

Line 19:

```
<meta property="og:article:published_time" content="2013-05-07T23:31:07Z" />
```

Line 207:

```
<span class="updated" title="2013-05-8"><time datetime="2013-05-08 02:31:07" pubdate>| 8 May 2013</time></span></span>
```

Edit: would it be possible to do this with python and beautiful soup using the Open Graph tags?

Comment: Your question is very unclar. Please specify what methods you would like to use, and what programming language. I mean, there are many ways of doing this.

Comment: The method is not very important to me, i am running Linux and bash, so anything that works there. Otherwise something based on the example above, if it that would be easy to alter.

Comment: Well, personally, I would create a node.js program just because that is what i can do best. By simply using the "fs" package from npm (file-system), it is possible to do what you want. If you want to, I can code a program which you run from the command prompt, but it requires you to install node.js.

Comment: Do not use old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses. Like this: `for f in $(find . -type f | grep \.html)`

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I will change it to parentheses. I already have node.js and npm installed, a script would be very appreciated.

Comment: The next step is to show us how publication date is represented in your html files.

Comment: See [why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Comment: Thank you, i can add the following in the question later. There are 2 places where the pubdate is given. 1) <span class="updated" title="2014-07-11"><time datetime="2014-07-11 12:20:03" pubdate>| 11 juillet 2014</time></span></span> and 2) <meta property="og:article:published_time" content="2014-07-11T09:20:03Z" />

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input (samples of the files you want to parse) and expected output (the text you want to extract from those files). Don't add relevant information in comments where we have to search for it and it can't be formatted legibly - put everything anyone needs to know to be able to help you in your question.

Comment: Okay I will create a github repository and link it here, give me a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent some time doing some guesswork, your question isn't very clear, but I arrived at this solution:

I have made a git repo called [renamer](https://github.com/MindChirp/renamer). This quick little script can be run from inside the folder with all your index files, and it will fetch all the .html files in the folder and rename them to the text inside the `<title>` tag of the respective html file plus the date it was published, which I fetched from one of the meta tags in the html file. This script assumes the structure of the meta tag in your html element, so it should work as long as the meta tag structure stays the same.

**NOTE:** 
The files you download from github have to be placed inside a folder which is inside the directory of your html files (see the images below)

*You probably already know this*, but when you have placed the files in the folder, run `npm install` in the folder of the program. This will install all the required dependencies, which are in this case `file-system`, `path` and `readline`.

To run the program type `node main` in the folder of the program, and just like that, all the html files in the parent folder will be renamed.

[image: The files before the program has been engaged]

[image: The files after the program has been engaged]

[image: The command to run inside of the folder containing my program]

[image: The folder in which the downloaded files should be located]

In theory, you should be able to keep the program in the folder where your index files are located for future use as well. Very handy if you ever quickly need to change some names in the future :)

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and the code you wrote, it works great !!!

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extra the pub date using sed from the meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:article:published_time" content="2013-05-07T23:31:07Z" />
```

Using `sed`script to extra pub_date in YYYYMMDD

```
pub_date=$(sed -n -e 's/.*meta property.*published_time.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\).*/\1\2\3/p')
```

The code is 'opportunistic', and assume very specific structure of the meta tag. However, for quick and dirty solution - it will work. Use $pub_date to construct the file name

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it doesn't seem to work with me. I tried to rename the file only using $pub_date in the code from my question and nothing happens ... ie This code: for f in $(find . -type f | grep \.html)
   do
   pub_date=$(sed -n -e 's/.*meta property.*published_time.*\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\).*/\1\2\3/p')
   mv -i "$f" "$pub_date".html
done

Comment: @badaboum looks like you have a solution. If you still need help, please post the result of running the solution (use 'set -x' before running the logic), and share output in a question.